# Internal compiler error occurring at build uwp C#

Tags: c#, uwp

I tried to build my uwp app but an internal compiler error occurred.
I deleted the bin and obj files and tried building again, but it didn't work.

[image]
Error message occurred

https://github.com/Sunday5214/Catch_The_Covid_19/tree/master/UWP/CatchTheCovid19_UWPClient

This is the GitHub link for the project. I think it's a dependency issue and attach it

No matter how googled I see no similar example.
I hope there is someone who can fix this

[image]

[image]

After commenting out the problem line

[image]

Comment: Please share the full error log

Comment: I changed the picture to the entire output window. Are you saying this?

Comment: Additionally, the error only occurs on release.
It works so well when debugging.

Comment: Is the Logger task causing the build failure? Does it build both in debug and release mode when you remove this logger task?

Comment: The corresponding tag was commented from line 801 where an error occurs.
However, only the name of the error changes and the release still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the repo and tried to build, but there are many errors. I did some modifications:

1. In RestManager.cs, i modified line 53:

   ```
   T resp = default(T);
   ```
2. Project CatchTheCovid19.Serial built unsuccessfully. I checked the CatchTheCovid19.Serial.csproj file, found out that the path of the references is using with relative path. I'm not sure why you were using with relative path.I changed them to absolute path, the solution built without any errors. Hope that help with you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in fact, I tried to find the problem by excluding it by reference and trying several times.
Still, your answers helped solve other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your log settings to generate detailed log rather than normal logs. That may help give you more clues. Check [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2019). In the settings change the verbosity to `Diagnostic`. See if that helps. Also you have a warning. See if you can fix that. Wild guess, but that may also be causing the compiler to fail.

[image]

Comment: After changing the build configuration as you said, I figured out which file is causing the error. But I still don't know why the error occurred.